How to find range subset statements for 2x2 block matrices
I am currently dealing with 2x2 block matrices. In my quest of understanding some basics, I discovered the following Lemma:

Let $A \geq 0$. Given a subspace $S$, partition $A$ as before:
\begin{equation}
 A = \left( \begin{split} A_{11} & A_{12} \\ A_{21} & A_{22} \end{split} \right)
 \end{equation}
Then range$A_{21} \subseteq$ range$A_{22}$ and ker$A_{22} \subseteq$ ker$A_{12}$.

I know that for instance, one can formulate a row or column inclusion property using the $LU$-factorization of $A$ to prove similar statements for $A_{11}$. However, I fail to do that for the block $A_{22}$ since it involves two summed expressions when written out in terms of the blocks of $L$ and $U$.
My question now is how to prove the above Lemma, either with a column inclusion statement or any other technique that I am missing.
